# Highcharts.js cannot see graph line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working on a line chart using highcharts.js on localhost.

I have tried implementing more than 20,000 records and it works smoothly 
like a charm.

But I have a `json` file which contains 11,000 records, but due to some
unknown reason it does not show me the graph line when I run it.

If I place a check that shows me less than three thousand records then 
I see the line.

Just copy paste the code in an html file and it should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background:#212224;">

<div id="container" style="max-width: 1666px;  margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button id="button">Destroy the chart</button>
<button id="create">create the chart</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

      $('#button').click(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts().destroy();
            });

     $('#create').click(function (){
    $.getJSON('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76618626/data2.json', function (data) {
        console.log("data size is : ");
        console.log(data.data.length);      

        var data3 = [];

        //you can comment this loop and uncomment the loop below for working code.      
        $.each(data.data,function(i,d){
            data3.push([new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(),d.value])
            });

        //below is commented code which works for 3000 records.

        //$.each(data.data,function(i,d){
        //if(i<3000){
        //      data3.push([new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(),d.value])
        //      }
        //});



        console.log(data3);

        $('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
                },

            title: {
                text: 'Test Graph',
                style: {
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: {
                    text: 'Time Stamp'
                },
                gridLineColor: 'grey',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                lineWidth:1

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                gridLineColor: 'grey',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                lineWidth:1
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            exporting: false,



            plotOptions: {
                line: {                 
                    lineColor: 'red',
                    fillOpacity: 1,                    
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null,
                    marker: {
                        fillColor: '#e57255'
                        }


                },


            },


            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'test',
                data: data3
            }]
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that your problem is connected with your data, Not all of your data is correct and that is the reason why you have this problem. Here you can find an example how it will work with correct data: http://jsfiddle.net/pg5gjogb/3/

Comment: Thank you so much !!!... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your data is correctly formatted, currently there is data that is not correctly formatted.  You can perform a quick check using something like this:

```
$.each(data.data,function(i,d){
    // Return if value is not a number
    if (isNaN(parseInt(d.value))) return;
    data3.push([new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(),d.value])
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/03czovaa/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !!!!!!
....this issue was driving me crazy.

Comment: @Steve don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (green tick) so that future users may benefit too!